# How to copy html element in Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dom, angular-components

what is angular alternative for this Jquery:

```
var data = $("#someid").html();
$("#someid").html(data+"custom text");
```

How .html(), .append(), .text() methods of jquery  works in AngularJS?

Comment: Databinding is the answer.

Answer (score -1):

There is no straight mapping between jQuery and AngularJS in that fashion, as Angular is sort of a paradigm shift from the jQuery way of doing things on the DOM.

The one answer for all of your questions is **[AngularJS directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)**

For `html`, i.e. if you want to replace or populate a tag with some `html` content, you can use `ng-include` or create a custom template directive and use it as an Element, Attribute, Class etc.

For `text`, you can use the `ng-bind` directive to two-way bind your text on your controller with your HTML tag on your view.

For e.g.

#### .text()

```
// View
<p ng-bind="name"></p>
// Controller
$scope.name = "Yourname";
```

#### .html()

```
<ng-include="partial.html"></ng-include>
// Define `partial.html` in your codebase
```